# When you explicitly load a DBSet, why doesn't it first remove existing elements?

Tags: entity-framework

New to EF. Trying to figure out differences between "filling" a DataTable of a DataSet and "loading" a DBSet.

If I fill a DataTable of a DataSet, the records that are present prior to the "fill" are removed. This allows me to have just the records in the DataTable that want. I could also choose not to have records removed prior to the "fill". But I have control of what's in the DataTable.

When I explicitly "load" a DBSet, it doesn't remove any entities that are already in it, just adds on top. So, unlike the DataTable, it seems that the DBSet is incrementally filled. If I "Clear()" the DBSet.Local, the Local.Count becomes zero, but the entities that were cleared are still loaded (when I test with IsLoaded) somewhere. And, I can't seem to get them back into .Local with another "load", because they are already loaded.

Hmmmm. Is this as it's supposed to be? Must I keep data in memory? Can't I selectively unload entities (without Deleting them of course) and reload them later?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for the opposite of Attach. Functionally, it would remove an entity from memory without marking it for Deletion. But I don't see a method like this, leading me to believe that once it's in memory, I'm supposed to leave it there

Answer (score 0):

Found something useful:

```
                Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

This seems to remove the entity from memory (and the .Local) without marking it for Deletion from the database when you SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  A DbSet and a DataTable are not the same thing and you cannot compare them or their functionality.  What exactly do you mean by "Loading" a DbSet?  Three is no Load method in DbSet, though there is a Load Extension method that does nothing but fill the Local cache with the objects of the query.

This text from the documentation is very telling:

"This is equivalent to calling ToList and then throwing away the list without the overhead of actually creating the list."

I also think you are trying to use your DbContext as an in-memory database, which is not what it's designed for.  There Is no mechanism in EF to clean up the DbContext or prune its contents.  Detach, as you've found does some work, but only some of it...

DbContext is designed to be short lived.  You create a new one each time you need to make a query, then you dispose of it.  That's how it's supposed to be used.